# Corrupted struct data

Tags: c

I am working on a programming exercise in C, finding all substrings of length n in a given input string. Overall, my code appears to work. But whenever the number of substrings reaches 3 or more, the first substring in my struct becomes corrupted.

**series.h**

```
typedef struct slices {
   unsigned int substring_count;
   char **substring;
} slices_t;
```

**series.c**

```
#include "series.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void print_struct(slices_t *slices) {
    printf("Slices Struct\n");
    printf("-substring_count: %d\n", slices->substring_count);
    printf("-slices:\n");
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < slices->substring_count; i++)
        printf("--%s\n", slices->substring[i]);
}


slices_t slices(char *input_text, unsigned int substring_length) {
    printf("original input: %s\n", input_text);

    // determine size
    unsigned int array_size = 1 + strlen(input_text) - substring_length;
    printf("array_size: %d\n", array_size);

    // build struct
    slices_t *s = malloc(sizeof(slices_t));
    s->substring_count = 0;
    s->substring = malloc(sizeof(char) * array_size);

    if (substring_length == 0 || substring_length > strlen(input_text))
        return *s;

    // create slices
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < array_size; i++) {
        char *new_sub = malloc(substring_length * sizeof(char) + 1);
        for (unsigned int j=0; j < substring_length; j++) {
            new_sub[j] = *(input_text + i + j);
        }
        new_sub[substring_length] = '\0';
        printf("found new sub: %s\n", new_sub);
        s->substring[i] = new_sub;
        s->substring_count++;
        print_struct(s);
    }

    print_struct(s);
    return *s;
}
```

**output when testing on input = "918493904243" and substring_length = 5**

```
original input: 918493904243
array_size: 8
found new sub: 91849
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 1
-slices:
--91849
found new sub: 18493
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 2
-slices:
--91849
--18493
found new sub: 84939
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 3
-slices:
--�+���
--18493
--84939
found new sub: 49390
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 4
-slices:
--�+���
--18493
--84939
--49390
found new sub: 93904
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 5
-slices:
--�+���
--�+���
--84939
--49390
--93904
found new sub: 39042
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 6
-slices:
--�+���
--�+���
--84939
--49390
--93904
--39042
found new sub: 90424
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 7
-slices:
--�+���
--�+���
--�+���
--49390
--93904
--39042
--90424
found new sub: 04243
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 8
-slices:
--�+���
--�+���
--�+���
--49390
--93904
--39042
--90424
--04243
Slices Struct
-substring_count: 8
-slices:
--�+���
--�+���
--�+���
--49390
--93904
--39042
--90424
--04243
```

Note that it only becomes corrupt when the substring_count reaches 3 and becomes further corrupted at every other new substring. And the corrupted value is not consistent. Multiple runs produce different corrupted values. And this happens with input strings of varying lengths and different substring lengths.

Comment: Can you turn this into a [mcve] by adding a main function to call your functions with input that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Have you tried tools like valgrind and AddressSanitizer?

Comment: Can we see your main?

Comment: The code is called by a testing harness, so I don't have my own main function. @yun correctly spotted my error, which was that I allocated memory for an array of char instead of an array of char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that memory becomes corrupted, but that the program tries to read/write outside of allocated memory.

This line is problematic:

```
s->substring = malloc(sizeof(char) * array_size);
```

The amount of memory it allocates is for `sizeof(char)`, but should be for `sizeof(char*)`. So:

```
s->substring = malloc(sizeof(char*) * array_size);
```

This solves the invalid reads and writes. There still are memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. The testing harness takes care of freeing the allocated memory.